# How to make a JavaScript function use less memory (image rotation in background)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cpu-usage

I have a function which rotates a background image on a webpage really slowly (it's a starfield). The function is as follows:

```
function changeAngle() {
            setAngle = setInterval(bgrotate,50);
        }

        function bgrotate(){
            i+=0.1;
            var sCSS= ("rotate(" + i + "deg)");
            $("#starfield").css({ '-moz-transform': sCSS, '-o-transform': sCSS, '-webkit-transform': sCSS });
        }
```

The image it's rotating is 610kB.

It works really well, but I've noticed that the fan on my machine really heats up when I'm running the page. I've checked the activity monitor and the CPU is up at around 85%.

Anyone any ideas how I can streamline this a bit to reduce CPU usage? If you need, I can put up a demo version of the page to see it running.

Thanks a mill,

T

UPDATE: Demo of this page available here: http://tady.me/rbg

FINAL QUESTION ON THIS: Hi folks, I may need to start a new question, but just in case any of the people who helped originally can tell me, any idea why this wouldn't be working in Safari (Mac + PC) or Firefox (PC Only)?

Cheers,

T

Comment: I want to see a demo of this.

Comment: Is it about memory usage or CPU usage?

Comment: @Nick No worries Nick, gimme a minute. @Felix I'm not really sure. It's the first time I've been concerned about the way a page is using resources, so apologies if I've tagged this incorrectly.

Comment: You could put `$('#starfield')` into a separate variable once to speed things up at least, might save memory too.

Comment: Cheers, all. I've updated the content with a link to a demo...

Comment: @tadywankenobi: Hui.... it really uses the whole CPU...

Comment: My memory in Chrome 10 is quite stable when running your demo. The rotation however is not completely accurate for some reason.

Comment: @Felix yeah, it does! I'm looking at it in Chrome 10 on the Mac. Really seeing it eating up the CPU. @pimvdb Weird pim, cause on mine it's the other way around. I'd really like to look into CD Sanchez's answer below, but I'm not sure how to implement it infinitely (so it's always turning). Any ideas?

Comment: Funny, not a monster in Firefox4... Well it's deffo webkit. Safari goes to 65% and Chrome to 85%.

Comment: @tadywankenobi: I too have Chrome 10 on a Mac and In mine it is really 98%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try doing this with CSS (using the transition or animation timing properties) rather than with JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions

**Demo (webkit)**: http://jsfiddle.net/E9J77/2/

Unfortunately Firefox still doesn't support CSS animations.

Here's a work around for Firefox using the transitionend event:

**Demo (Firefox)**: http://jsfiddle.net/VZhnh/3/

Comment: I thought about this CD but couldn't work out a way to make it run infinitely. Any ideas?

Comment: Works better, but still uses like ~50% CPU in Chrome 10 on my Mac (but maybe one cannot do better...)

Comment: CD You are an absolute star. I never knew there was an animation iteration count of infinite!!! Amazing, exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much. I'm going to try that right now!!!

Comment: @tadywankenobi: Thanks :) I added another jsfiddle link with a workaround for firefox.

Comment: That's great, thanks CD!!! I've a lot of this working, so gonna put conditional code for Firefox. It seems the size of the image is what's causing the CPU soakage. It is quite big, but I want it to look like a true starfield. I'll see if I can do something with a smaller tiled image... Cheers all!!!

Comment: I've updated to a better (tiling) image, added the Firefox and Webkit solutions and I must say... It looks pretty damn sweet!!! Still chugging a lot of CPU, but I'll see what I can do about that...

Comment: Hey CD, one small thing. Any idea why it's not working in Safari?!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting technique -- I also want to see a demo.

What about increasing the interval? Have you tried 100 ms and rotate .2degs?

Comment: @drnessie & @typeof Thanks for that suggestion guys, but if I increase the interval and the steps, it moves more jerky. I want a smooth, almost unnoticeable movement.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the interval slightly larger, but then also increasing the distance each rotation gives.

I would also suggest saving #starfield to a global variable, to decrease DOM access

(of course, transitions only work in Firefox, Safari and I think chrome)

Comment: Of course it only works in those browsers. This is just a proof of concept to myself. I just want to see it can be done.